# Python cannot import class

Tags: python, flask

My problem is: I am unable to import the model's `Role` class (Or anything from the models for that matter).
I have a simple file structure in my Flask app (theres more but the problem is here):

```
myapp 
|--serve.py
|--models.py
|--front.py
```

In models.py:

```
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
     description = db.Column(db.String(255))
...
```

In my serve.py:

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

In my front.py:

```
class SetupUserForm(Form):
    from models import Role
    roles = RadioField(choices=[(r.name,r.name.title()) for r in Role.query.all()],validators=[validators.Required()])
```

I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Role
```

This is the gist. 
I can import the `app` from the model.
I have tried adding in an `__init__.py` file in the myapp (the main) directory. 
I do not understand imports 100%.

Comment: sorry, I just saw that :)

Comment: @aIKid Does it count as a circular import if `serve.py` imports `front.py`. `front.py` imports `models.py`. `models.py` imports `serve.py`?

Comment: Most likely. Check it out.